# Multiply without multiplication, division and bitwise operators, and no loops. Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class MultiplyViaRecursion{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("8 * 9 == " + multiply(8, 9));
        System.out.println("6 * 0 == " + multiply(6, 0));
        System.out.println("0 * 6 == " + multiply(0, 6));
        System.out.println("7 * -6 == " + multiply(7, -6));
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y){
        int result = 0;

        if(y > 0)
            return result = (x + multiply(x, (y-1)));
        if(y == 0)
            return result;
        if(y < 0)
            return result = -multiply(x, -y);   

        return result;
    }
}
```

My question is very simple and basic, why after each "if" the "return" still cannot pass the compilation, error shows missing return.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: He posted code that compiles; he is asking why if he removes the final `return` statement why the compiler fails.

Answer (score 6):

To put it simply: the Java compiler isn't that smart.  It can't deduce that one of your three  `if` statements **must** evaluate to true.  And since the compiler believes there is a chance all the `if` conditions can fail, it thinks it's possible to go beyond the `if` blocks, at which point there is no `return` statement.

Instead, try using an `if else` block, like so.

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
    int result = 0;

    if (y > 0)
        return result = (x + multiply(x, (y - 1)));
    else if (y == 0)
        return result;
    else 
        return result = -multiply(x, -y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler cannot guess that your three IFs cover all the cases.
If you want to simplify the code, you can remove the last IF that is unnecessary :

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y){
    int result = 0;
    if(y > 0)
        return result = (x + multiply(x, (y-1)));
    if(y == 0)
        return result;
    return result = -multiply(x, -y);   
}
```

By the way, you can also remove the `result` variable :

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y){
    if(y > 0)
        return (x + multiply(x, (y-1)));
    if(y == 0)
        return 0;
    return -multiply(x, -y);   
}
```